# Book with a young boy, maybe teenage, who becomes friendly with aliens who upload information in to his brain

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I read a book, possible several in a series, about 20 years ago in which a boy befriends aliens who upload information in to his brain. They uploaded books and useful information and things like that. It's a fairly light-hearted book with some dramatic bits thrown in to it. If I remember correctly there was some action parts where the boy must save the Earth or the aliens, something to that effect.

Comment: Hi, and welcome so SF&F.  There is are some [guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) that suggest other things that might help people recognize the story.  For example, where were you when you read this?

Comment: Sounds kind of like a novelization of *Flight of the Navigator*